# A question about trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

If a trigonometric equation has an infinite number of solutions, is it true that the equation is an identity?

Please explain.

Comment: The equation $\sin x=0$ has infinitely many solutions, but $\sin x=0$ is not an identity.

Comment: Rather we can say an equation having more than $1$ trigonometric ratio like $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ it has infinite solutions so yes its an identity

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: "$\sin x = \cos x$" has two trigonometric ratios and infinitely-many solutions, but it is not an identity.

Comment: No but mine one holds fir any x not so with yours @Blue

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Your statement "it has infinite solutions **so** yes it[']s an identity" (emphasis mine) suggests that having infinitely-many solutions is enough to guarantee the identity-ness of an equation with two or more trig ratios. My example illustrates that this isn't true. The "holds f[o]r any $x$ [in the domain]" property is, of course, the actual requirement for identity-ness ... but it's also effectively the *definition* of "identity".

Answer (score 1):

> If a trigonometric equation has an infinite number of solutions, is it true that the equation is an identity?

As mentioned in the comments, an example of an equation that has infinitely many solutions would be $\sin(x)=0$, but for it to be an *identity*, it has to hold for *any* $x$, which is not true $($it is only true for $x=n\pi, \; n \in \mathbb{Z})$.

An example of an identity (which holds for any ol' $x$) is $$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$

Sometimes, there are restrictions on what $x$ can be. For instance, De Moivre's theorem

$$\left(\cos\theta +i\sin\theta \right)^n=\cos n\theta +i\sin n\theta$$

is only true when $n$ is an integer, but we would still say that that is an identity.

Comment: @dan Does it make sense now, or should I elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is a statement or re-statement of a law, property or theorem of a particular geometric configuration (e.g., Pythagoras theorem , propositions of Euclid) then its inter relations form an identity for all values of a geometric variable like length or angle.